# Поиск суммы элементов в матрице. Python

Tags: python

Возможно ли найти сумму элементов под диагональю в матрице (двумерном массиве) с помощью функциональной парадигмы(без циклов, условных операторов)?

Comment: Да, это возможно

Comment: Не понятно только с каких пор условные операторы противоречат функциональной парадигме

Comment: @insolor возможно, вопрошающий не противопоставлял циклы функциональной парадигме, а перечислил это вот все как совместные условия задачи.

Comment: хорошо бы все же,чтобы вопрошающий вопросил ясно.

Comment: подскажите, какие команды нужно использовать для этого тогда, если это возможно

Comment: for i in range(1, n):
    s2 += sum(lst[i][-i:])
    for j in range(i):
        s += lst[i][j]
я честно без понятия как это переделать под эту парадигму